# Getting a transaction is undefined error with a Phone gapp application

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap

I'm getting the following error.

```
index.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
```

I'm using phone gapp to try and build an app for the iOS. I've added the cordova-sqlite-storage to the project, and my phone gapp desktop application is selecting the right project. I've also added the corrrect platforms to the project so i'm not so sure what is going on.

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myDB;
//Open Database Connection
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default'});
}
//Create new table
$("#createTable").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonegap_pro (id integer primary key, title text, desc text)', [],
        function(tx, result) {
            alert("Table created successfully");
        }, 
        function(error) {
              alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
        });
    });
});

//Insert New Data
$("#insert").click(function(){
  var title=$("#title").val();
  var desc=$("#desc").val();
  console.log(title +""+ desc);
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
      alert("insert clicked");
        var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO phonegap_pro (title, desc) VALUES (?,?)";             
        transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc]
            , function(tx, result) {
                 alert('Inserted');
            },
            function(error){
                 alert('Error occurred'); 
            });
    });
});

//Display Table Data
$("#showTable").click(function(){
  $("#TableData").html("");
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM phonegap_pro', [], function (tx, results) {
      alert("show clicked");
       var len = results.rows.length, i;
       $("#rowCount").html(len);
       for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
          $("#TableData").append("<tr><td>"+results.rows.item(i).id+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).title+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).desc+"</td><td><a href='edit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id+"&title="+results.rows.item(i).title+"&desc="+results.rows.item(i).desc+"'>Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class='delete' href='#' id='"+results.rows.item(i).id+"'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
       }
    }, null);
  });
});

//Delete Data from Database
$(document.body).on('click', '.delete' ,function(){
  var id=this.id;
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
      alert("delete clicked");
    var executeQuery = "DELETE FROM phonegap_pro where id=?";
    transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [id],
      //On Success
      function(tx, result) {alert('Delete successfully');},
      //On Error
      function(error){alert('Something went Wrong');});
  });
});


//Delete Tables
$("#update").click(function(){
  var id=$("#id").text();
  var title=$("#title").val();
  var desc=$("#desc").val()
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    var executeQuery = "UPDATE phonegap_pro SET title=?, desc=? WHERE id=?";
    transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc,id],
      //On Success
      function(tx, result) {alert('Updated successfully');},
      //On Error
      function(error){alert('Something went Wrong');});
  });
});

$("#DropTable").click(function(){
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
        var executeQuery = "DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS phonegap_pro";
        transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [],
            function(tx, result) {alert('Table deleted successfully.');},
            function(error){alert('Error occurred while droping the table.');}
        );
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the plugin is closing the SQLITE connection.  Try assigning myDB in each function call like this:

```
//Insert New Data
$("#insert").click(function(){
  var title=$("#title").val();
  var desc=$("#desc").val();
  console.log(title +""+ desc);
  let myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default'});
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {...
```